# OpenCV Mat in function return and using copyTo

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have this snippet to perform inverse of a homogeneous matrix

```
Mat invHom(const Mat A)
{
    Mat invA = Mat::eye(4,4,CV_64FC1);
    Mat R, P;

    A(Range(0,3), Range(0,3)).copyTo(R);
    A(Range(0,3), Range(3,4)).copyTo(P);

    invA(Range(0,3), Range(0,3)) = R.t();
    invA(Range(0,3), Range(3,4)) = -R.t()*P;
    return invA;
}
```

is this code tend to error? since invA, R, P are Mat created in function scope. Does the "return" of the function perform creation & copying to a new Mat object (i.e. Mat::copyTo()) so that value of invA is still available outside the function?

Sorry for my bad English and terms of programming

one with no error:

```
int invHom(const Mat A, Mat& invA_ou)
{
    Mat invA = Mat::eye(4,4,CV_64FC1);

    Mat R, P;
    A(Range(0,3), Range(0,3)).copyTo(R);
    A(Range(0,3), Range(3,4)).copyTo(P);

    //invA(Range(0,3), Range(0,3)) = R.t();
    //invA(Range(0,3), Range(3,4)) = -R.t()*P;

    Mat tmp1 = R.t();
    tmp1.copyTo(invA(Range(0,3), Range(0,3)));

    Mat tmp = -R.t()*P;
    tmp.copyTo(invA(Range(0,3), Range(3,4)));

    invA.copyTo(invA_ou);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is ok. `Mat` is an object basically composed by an header and the actual data. When you copy a `Mat`  you're copying the header only, not the data (that's why it's very fast). When you copy, an internal reference counter is incremented. When the reference counter is zero, data will be released.
To perform a deep copy, you need the method `clone()` or `copyTo(...)`.

So, in your case you're fine.

You can look at OpenCV doc [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#memory-management-and-reference-counting) for further details.

An alternative coding style would be to pass the output matrix as argument, like:

```
void invHom(const Mat& A, Mat& invA)
{
    invA = Mat::eye(4,4,CV_64FC1);
    Mat R, P;

    A(Range(0,3), Range(0,3)).copyTo(R);
    A(Range(0,3), Range(3,4)).copyTo(P);

    invA(Range(0,3), Range(0,3)) = R.t();
    invA(Range(0,3), Range(3,4)) = -R.t()*P;        
}
```

Note that passing references (`&`) to `Mat`, you don't even copy the header.

Comment: problem is my copying is made from objects created inside function, so after function returns, the main caller will not receive this value

Comment: Your return statement will copy the Mat (header) that will increment the reference counter for the data created inside the function. When you exit the function, the ref counter will be decreased, but the data won't be canceled because they are still referenced by the returned Mat

Comment: If you want to be sure, just return invA.clone(), but this is an unnecessary deep copy.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I'd like to know more about this mechanism of increment of reference counter and decrement of it when function exists. Could you help me with some terms i.e. c/c++ terms?

Comment: @ShawnLe your alternative solution will work, but you're still doing unnecessary copies. See my update answer for an example.

Comment: @Miki: Ciao!  I have a question for you if you don't mind and along the same topic: If you use `cv::Mat::copyTo` with a mask, what happens to the pixels in the output matrix for the elements where the mask is equal to 0? Is the behaviour different when the output matrix is already allocated in comparison to being uninitialized? I can't find this behaviour in the docs or on StackOverflow. Sorry to bug you in a comment, but I'd rather ask in a comment than a question to be safe :) Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ray no problem :) I should check (tomorrow probably), but... 0 elements in mask are not copied. If the matrix is uninitialized, the matrix is created zero initialized (should check)  of the correct size, and then as before. I never used copyTo with a mask. Probably setTo is what you need.

Comment: @Miki `setTo` is indeed better for me.  Basically I need any values that are not in the mask to be set to 0, so I would just use `setTo` on the opposite of the mask.  I also just checked now in the source: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L335 and it confirms that you are correct.  Thank you for the verification and for the tip!