# copyto() and clone functions in open cv

Tags: c++, opencv

when we save a image using cv::Mat we know in the header of the Mat object it has the destination of the pixels (pointer to image location) so by using copy to function to another object in Mat class is it create a separate copy of the pixels or pointing to the same memory location ?

Comment: thank u .. this thing clears my mind

Answer (score 8):

`.copyTo` AND `.clone()` will both (deep)copy the pixel data, not only the header, so in most cases it will allocate new memory and in even more cases memory to the source will not be shared.

However, if the destination matrix already has allocated memory and the image size and type is identical to the new source, `.copyTo` will not allocate new memory but (deep)copy the pixel data to the already present allocated memory.

For example:

---

This code will allocate new memory for `destination` and copy the pixels of source to it, so source and destination won't share the memory.

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread(...);
cv::Mat destination;
source.copyTo(destination);
```

---

This code will use the earlier allocated memory but still copy the pixels to destination, so `.copyTo` will NOT allocate new memory, but pixels are copied, so source and destination won't share memory.

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread(...);
cv::Mat destination = cv::Mat(source.size(), source.type()); // this will allocate memory fitting the data of source
source.copyTo(destination);
```

---

This code might (not 100% sure, I didnt test it) share the memory, since destination might not allocate new memory and source and destination use the same memory BEFORE .copyTo:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread(...);
cv::Mat destination = source; // now they use the same memory
source.copyTo(destination); // since destination size and type do fit source size and type, MAYBE no new memory is allocated!
```

---

---

afaik, `.clone()` will ALWAYS allocate new memory. Another difference between `.copyTo` and `.clone` is the possibiliy to use a `mask` in `.copyTo`

---

another thing to mention: `.clone()` will always create a continuous matrix, even if the original matrix had additional bytes at the end of each pixel line that didn't hold any pixel data (this padding can be used for example to enable hardware optimization if the number of bytes per row doesn't fulfill the requirements for hardware optimization).

Comment: Hi Micka.  Question for you: If you use `cv::Mat::copyTo` with a mask, what happens to the pixels in the output matrix for the elements where the mask is equal to 0?  Is the behaviour different when the output matrix is already allocated in comparison to being uninitialized?  I can't find this behaviour in the docs or on StackOverflow.  Sorry to bug you in a comment, but I'd rather ask in a comment than a question to be safe :) Thanks.

Comment: @rayryeng I didn't try it yet. It's an interesting question!

Comment: Herr Micka.  No problem :) I talked to Miki and I also looked at the source code for `copyTo`.  Our thread is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443288/opencv-mat-in-function-return-and-using-copyto/31443544?noredirect=1#comment70735168_31443544.  Basically if you use `copyTo` with a mask and the output matrix is uninitialized, the output is created to match the size of the input and is set to `cv::Scalar(0)` prior to copy.  If the matrix is initialized, a copy of the matrix is made with those elements in the mask being non-zero being copied over.  I think I will use `setTo` instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying regardless :)